# Inline image won't show up on HTML email

Tags: html, email, html-email

I have an HTML email with an image tag whose source is dynamically generated. It's like:

```
<div>
    <img src="http://www.example.com/image/foo"></img>
</div>
```

Let's say the link has proper mime type, content disposition filename.jpg and the image shows up on the browser. But when it's inside an email, it is not rendered. I have other images on the HTML but are hosted physically like http://www.example.com/path/to/image.jpg, and this perfectly shows up.

Do email clients block images that are not physically located on the server? By the way, I can't change the dynamic url of the image to end it with a file extension like http://www.example.com/image/foo.png

Comment: `http://www.example.com/image/foo` is not a valid image url and that is why the image is not shown.

Comment: I said "It's like." I already pointed out the assumptions.

Comment: That I understood @macdelacruz.. I was saying that the image url should contain a valid image extension like for eg `.png`, `.jpg` etc.

Comment: Even if the image shows in browser? The image is base64 decoded from the database, so maybe I can just resolve http://www.example.com/image/foo.jpg to http://www.example.com/image/foo just so it can be rendered in emails?